# How to create loop row values in mysql

Tags: mysql, loops, hive

I've table with name df:

```
device_code             gender
Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A    male
samsung SM-G532G        female
Apple iPhone5           female
OPPO A37f               male
LENOVO Lenovo A6000     male
Apple iPhone5           male
```

I want to get values in every rows and put into select query in device_code of this query:

```
select log10(total_redmi / total_male) as lmp_redmi
from (
         select sum(case
                        when gender = 'male' and device_code = 'Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A' then 1
                        else 0 end)                                                     as total_redmi,
                sum(case when gender = 'male' and gender is not null then 1 else 0 end) as total_male
         from df) x
```

so I didn't input manually every row values in device_code into the above query. 
in my query above the output like:

```
lmp_redmi     lmp_SMG532G   ... etc
-0,602059991    0
```

but i expected the output like this:

```
                                  lmp   
Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A    -0,602059991    
samsung SM-G532G         0              
Apple iPhone5,3         -0,602059991    
OPPO A37f               -0,602059991    
LENOVO Lenovo A6000     -0,602059991
```

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?

Comment: Which version of MySql are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query was not wrong. I just want to get every row values into select query so i didnt input manually. like i want to know sum of Apple Iphones5 then the script is: select sum(case when gender = 'male' and device_code = 'Apple Iphones5' then 1 else 0 end) as total_apple. if i've 5000 kinds of device_code then there is 5000 select query. there is another simple way to solve this?

Comment: Please add the expected output from the input you did show us above.

Comment: @Sergey actually i used this query in Hive Ambari

Comment: If you're using Hive, then why did you tag with MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for something like this:

```
select *, case when total_device_male > 0
               then log10(total_device_male/total_male)
          end as lmp_redmi
from (
  select device_code, sum(case when gender = 'male' then 1 else 0 end) as total_device_male,
    (select count(*) from df where gender = 'male') as total_male
  from df
  group by device_code
)x
```

Comment: Thank youuu :) the output is like that i want